# Visual studio code - disable jupyter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide

I have problem with my VSC, when i hit Shift+Enter it execute selected line in Ipython, however when i hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER it starts jupyter notebook and execute whole file.

Is is possible to disable jupyter notebook ? 
Is is possible to make "CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER" to execute whole file in Ipython?